# Create a calendar inside my android application

Tags: android

I want to create a calendar inside my android application. This is the calendar that i want to include in my project. It is from github :

https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker.git

How to import this project in my app?

Comment: S.O. is not a coding service

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am asking the procedure to include this calendar into my project!!

Comment: @AnushkaSharma read this https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

> Go to the File > New > Import Module > select path ,
>     give module name and add the module
>
> Now go to the project setting gradle, add the module like this :
>   ':app', ':moduleName'
>
> Now go to the app gradle and implement your module like this : 
>   implementation project(':moduleName')

Comment: This is the right way to add library to android studio. You can also try this, both are same : https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio